# "etching" transparent conductor on transparent plastic film or glass?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, conductors, etching, plastic

I've put the word etching in quotations as the method to get conductive tracks on a glass or plastic film might not involve a subtractive approach as with traditional PCBs of applying a conductive layer (such as ITO in this case) and then removing the unneeded part, but rather an additive approach such as printing or drawing the tracks on a transfer medium sheet and somehow transferring it to the glass or plastic (such as PET) film, etc. later, or printing/drawing directly on the glass or plastic film somehow.

Need two transparent conductors in an arrangment like this on a transparent plastic film. Such as ITO on PET. But it doesn't have to be ITO necessarily.

[image]

Of course for others it can be anything else such as this.

[image]

There are too many tracks and their size and their gaps are going to be sub milimeter, so hand drawing is out of the question.

Will be running few milliamps and about 8 VDC. Size of the whole film is going to be 10 cm x 5 cm max.

Since one may need to run dozens or maybe hundreds of tests with different widths, gaps and arrangments, is there is a way to print conductive material on a PET or similar transparent film at home, such as with a modified laserjet or inkjet printer, or a modified mini CNC? What can/should one use for the transparent conductive "ink" and the film and what should one use to get their drawing from a digital file onto real film/glass?

Comment: change the word from "etching" to "laying"

Comment: eeek.. my eyes....

Comment: What chemical properties are necessary for the conductive tracks (ITO) in this "capacitor" geometry?  What dielectric properties? are needed for insulator (PET is well known to be low leakage). ITO is usually vacuum sputtered over a mask removed after.

Comment: That's quite the shopping list of requirements to do at home. Your best bet is probably a photographic process with plating of some sort. But way too specialised for me to comment much further than that.

Comment: Sorry Trevor, images like this merge into a solid color at lower resolution or as a thumbnail. Had to be done

Comment: A typical ITO conductive property and typical PET dielectric property is fine.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for "microlithography" which can be expensive if you need to buy the equipment but not too bad if there is a lab you can pay to use. ITO can be sputter deposited on just about anything, but this too isn't really doable at home.

Comment: coat the film with a resist and cure it with a video projector maybe? Like a stereolitography 3d printer but 2d?

Comment: I just learned something new today. Hadn't heard of ITO before. Interesting. Makes me interested in Fermi surfaces, again. I don't have a suggestion, though I'm sure the Gallium ion beam milling machines (from FEI) could do all the precision subtraction you could want. (Use them to do the fine detail milling work in creating the final version of disk drive heads out of the fuzzy lithography process that precedes it.) Pricey, though.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50234/etching-ito-on-pet-without-damage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy [glass](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1310) with Indium-Tin-Oxide coating and etch it with 55% HCL at room temperature. The Adafruit item is out of stock, but it should be possible to find other suppliers. Thickness of the ITO is 1850Å.

Etch rate is approximately 25Å (2.5nm) /second. Good results were [reported](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040609076900870?via%3Dihub) using [AZ 1350H](https://www.microchemicals.com/micro/introduction.pdf) photoresist. Total etch time would be less than 1.5 minutes.

You would need something like film and a vacuum exposure setup to get good resolution and exposure.

Comment: any ideas if it will work with ITO coated PET though?

Comment: Maybe. PET compatibility with 10% HCL is listed as "good", but "poor" against concentrated HCL. https://roboworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/PET_ChemicalCompatibility.pdf

Comment: As long as ITO can be etched with 10% HCL

Comment: @MarkLegault It might withstand more concentrated acid for the very short exposure time- a minute or two of etch time- or even the 10% acid might affect the transparency, especially if it has to sit for 20 or 30 minutes. Easy enough to try, except for the hazmat shipping charges on acid. Retail  hardware store muriatic acid is of reasonable intermediate strength but AFAIUI it may be more aggressive as it is not pure.

Comment: I think I should ask this in the chemistry stack exchange. It might be completely inert to plastics such as PET as its sold in plastic bottles and canisters.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88071/does-hydrochloric-acid-react-with-pet

Comment: Any chance there are more readily available photoresists usable for this?

Comment: I don't have a spinning apparatus so I would be tempted to try laminated dry film photoresist (especially for PET). There is generic stuff available from China. Think&Tinker used to sell name brand material, not sure if they still do.

Comment: Im sorry but what do you search to find a dry photoresist made for PET? Thank you.

Comment: @MarkLegault It's not made specifically for PET- it's made primarily for PCBs but some of those are made from similar plastics so it could work. Just look for "dry film photoresist". You need a laminator to do it right but since the plastic is thin it should work in a regular laminator (check the melting point lest you end up with a mess on the rollers). This is all a bit speculative. The acid resistance would be my main concern.

Comment: Think and tinker dry film $111 for 50' x 1'.   https://www.thinktink.com/products/Photoresist.asp Chinese generic $1.53 for ~3' x 1' (1m x 30cm) shipped (LOL).